# I am getting this expection "java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)" while connecting Hbase using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I am reading Hbase table using spark scala.

code is follows:

```
package HBase

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin, Result}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{ HBaseConfiguration, HTableDescriptor }
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import it.nerdammer.spark.hbase._
import org.apache.spark._

object Connector  {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {  

    val sparkConf = new        SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseApp").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    val tableName = "cars"

    conf.set("hbase.master", "10.163.12.87")
    conf.setInt("timeout", 40000)
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "10.163.12.87")
    conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure")
   conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)

    val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)
    if (!admin.isTableAvailable(tableName)) {
      val tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName)
      admin.createTable(tableDesc)
    }

    val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat],      classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
    println("Number of Records found : " + hBaseRDD.count())
    sc.stop()
     }
 }
```

I am getting below error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "16000��I���PBUF
HDP1.Node1�}ڞ���*

```
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HServerAddress.<init>(HServerAddress.java:63)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterAddressTracker.getMasterAddress(MasterAddressTracker.java:63)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:353)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:89)
at HBase.Connector$.main(Connector.scala:32)
at HBase.Connector.main(Connector.scala)
```

Comment: The exception is when you are trying to create table not when you read table? try to create table externally.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. But the error say Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "16000��I���PBUF HDP1.Node1�} 16000 is the Hbase master port.

Comment: You might have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019577/unable-to-connect-to-hbase-using-java

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
Tue Oct 04 12:35:49 IST 2016, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=81003: row 'cars,,00000000000000' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=hdp4.node4,16020,1475563582975, seqNum=0

Comment: Now i am getting the above exception

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the port number in the `hbase.master` config.

```
conf.set("hbase.master", "10.163.12.87:60000")
```

Comment: @Amit: did you try setting the port number for zookeeper quorum as well?